# What About AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I hear that Flash is starting to go away.  I know later this year Chrome is withdrawing support for it, and I wonder what is going to happen with it eventually.  I'm sad that so many people seem to not like Flash because it is the platform I have the most experience in.

Sidenote:  I know Flash is now renamed to Animate, and I figure Adobe was trying to rebrand probably so as to lose a little bit of the bad sentiments towards it(just a theory).

I know this is more of a "news" type question than a coding question, but does anyone know if Flash is going to continue to be a thing or should I bail before the bitter end?

Edit:  someone said something about air being a still supported platform for chrome or coding in flash in general.  Any more tips for how difficult/easy it would be to either transfer my code to it or starting a new project from scratch learning different coding syntax or is it mostly the same as AS3 in general.  I know a little bit of unity with C# would it be easier to switch over to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need a bit of background.

Flash or more specifically **Flash Player**, is a browser plugin that allows running ActionScript compiled for it.
There are other ActionScript compilers out there, such as the AIR compiler. Adobe AIR is not going away any time soon.

You'll be able to continue developing ActionScript 3 projects if you target them to AIR instead of Flash Player, after Flash Player is discontinued.

AIR can run on Windows, Mac, iOS, and Android.

---

On a side note - Flash Professional was most likely renamed to Animate since it does so much more than just produce "Flash Player" content. It can publish AIR, HTML5, and create animations at the very least.

Comment: Ah okay, I don't know if I've worked much with AIR.  Is the coding much different or is it almost as easy as copy/paste?  I was just worried that all the money I put into adobe flash monthly and all my experience in it would go to waste if it went away completely.  I can kind of see why the platform would be less desirable to people who are heavily into the more artsy aspect of the platform because even though it's called "animate" it does not do well with transitions if you want to change the shape of any lines in a complicated picture.

Comment: Well you added the jquery-animate tag to your question, it sounds like you're creating html5 content and not flash player content? AIR uses the same code. It has a couple added features on top of the base language as well.

Comment: Ah sorry about the mix up, that tag was a mistake.  I thought it would just be animate by itself.  I'm using action script 3.  On a side note, I was thinking about transferring my work to a new platform but if you say AIR is going to continue, then do you think the code would transfer easily?

Comment: Yes, I do think so. But does AIR target the platforms you need? Eg desktop, mobile app. There is a language called Haxe which is heavily influenced by AS3. There is a [AS3 to Haxe](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/as3hx) convertor script that somewhat works. You may be interested to learn about [Haxe](https://haxe.org/) and a library called [OpenFl](https://www.openfl.org/) which tries to duplicate all of ActionScript's functionality. Using [OpenFl](https://discord.gg/tDgq8EE) you can compile your Haxe code to Flash Player, desktop, html5, android, iOS you name it.